# Align beam endings at angled grating in pst-optexp

Tags: pstricks, pst-optexp

I am trying to replicate an optical setup used for CPA using `pst-optexp`. My current code is the following:

```
\begin{pspicture}(18,20)
    \Large
    \definecolor{passiveFiberColor}{HTML}{FF8000}
    \definecolor{activeFiberColor}{HTML}{0080FF}
    \definecolor{fiberLoopColor}{HTML}{8000FF}
    \definecolor{dispersionFiberColor}{HTML}{80FF00}
    \definecolor[ps]{bl}{rgb}{tx@addDict begin Red Green Blue end}%
    \psset[optexp]{fiber=none, usefiberstyle}
    
    \newpsstyle{Fiber}{linewidth=2\pslinewidth}
    \pnodes(1.5, 4){LaserIn}(2, 4){LaserOut}
    \pnodes (5, 4) {BSIn} (4, 3.5) {BSOut} (4, 4){BSCenter}
    \pnodes (7, 4) {MCenter} (6, 3) {Mout}
    \pnodes (5.5, 2.5) {GICenter} (6.5, 2.5) {GIOut}
    \pnodes (7.5, 2.5) {LIOut} (7, 2.5) {LICenter} (8, 2.5) {LIICenter} (8.5, 2.5) {LIIOut}
    \pnodes (10, 2.5) {GIICenter} (8.5, 3.5) {GIIOut}

    \drawbeam[beam, ArrowInside=->](LaserIn)(BSIn)


    
    %Stretcher stage
    \mirror[beam, mirrortype=extended, fillstyle=solid](BSIn)(MCenter)(Mout)
    \drawbeam[beam](Mout)(GICenter)
    %Fancy beams in stretcher
    \multido{\i=0+1}{40}{%
        \pstVerb{\i\space 650 400 sub 39 div mul 400 add tx@addDict begin wavelengthToRGB end}%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, beamangle=\i\space 16 sub 0.2 mul](GICenter)(LICenter)%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, loadbeampoints](LICenter)(LIICenter)%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, loadbeampoints, beamangle=\i\space 16 sub 0.125 mul -1 mul](LIICenter)(GIICenter)%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, loadbeampoints](GIICenter)(GIIOut)%
    }%
    \optgrating[reverse, angle=0, gratingalign=c, fillstyle=solid](Mout)(GICenter)(GIOut)
    \lens[fillstyle=solid](GIOut)(LIOut)
    \lens[fillstyle=solid](LIOut)(LIIOut)
    \optgrating[angle = 0, gratingalign = c, fillstyle=solid](LIIOut)(GIICenter)(GIIOut)
    \mirror[mirrortype=extended](GIICenter)(GIIOut)(GIICenter)
    
    %Amp stage
    \pnodes (4, 2.5) {AmpIn} (4, 0.5) {AmpOut}
    
    %Compressor stage
    \pnodes (4, -1) {BSIICenter} (5, -1) {BSIIOut}
    \pnodes (7, -1) {MIICenter} (6, 0) {MIIOut}
    \pnodes (5.5, 0.5) {GIIICenter} (6.5, 0.5) {GIIIOut}
    \pnodes (8.5, 0.5) {GIVCenter} (8, 1) {GIVOut}
    \pnode (7.5, -0.5) {MREFCenter}
    %Output
    \pnode(1.5, -1) {CPAOut}
    
    \drawbeam[beam, ArrowInside=->] (BSCenter) (AmpIn)
    \drawbeam[beam, ArrowInside=->] (AmpOut)(BSIICenter)
    \drawbeam[beam, ArrowInside=<->] (BSIICenter) (BSIIOut)
    \drawbeam[beam, ArrowInside = ->] (BSIICenter) (CPAOut)
    \pnodes (3.5, 2.5) {RectLowerX} (4.5, 0.5) {RectUpperX}
%   
    \beamsplitter(BSIn)(BSCenter)(BSOut){}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red!40!black](RectLowerX)(RectUpperX)
    

    
    \beamsplitter(AmpOut)(BSIICenter)(BSIIOut)
    \mirror[mirrortype=extended](BSIIOut)(MIICenter)(MIIOut)
    \mirror[beam, mirrortype=extended](GIVCenter)(MREFCenter)(GIVCenter)
    %Fancy beams in compressor
    \multido{\i=0+1}{40}{%
    \pstVerb{\i\space 650 400 sub 39 div mul 400 add tx@addDict begin wavelengthToRGB end}%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, beamangle=\i\space 16 sub 0.2 mul](GIIICenter)(GIVCenter)%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, loadbeampoints](GIVCenter)(MREFCenter)
    }%
    \drawbeam[beam](MIICenter)(GIIICenter)
    \optgrating[reverse, angle = 0, gratingalign = c, fillstyle=solid] (MIIOut)(GIIICenter)(GIIIOut)
    \optgrating[angle = -45, fillstyle=solid](GIIIOut)(GIVCenter)(MREFCenter)

    \drawbeam[beam] (MIICenter) (BSIIOut)

\end{pspicture}
```

My result looks like this:
[image]

It looks quite close to what I want, but in the lower compressor part I have issues with non-overlapping expanded beams. How can I fix that?

Sidenote: Yes, the code is messy, I'll have to clean up later, but if there are any improvements visible, I'm open for them, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage of `\drawbeam` is connecting components, without knowing about the actual shape, reflection and transmission behavior. You haven't used that at all, so that `\drawbeam` starts at a plane through the given node, but not at the grating component. That's what your observing as error in the compressor.

All your `\drawbeam` uses could have been replaced by `\psline`.

To connect components you can e.g. give them names with `compname`. You can find a very extensive description with many examples in section "9 Connecting components" of the `pst-optexp` manual.

Also, there is an `optexp` component, which draws components on top of the beams, although they are defined before the beams.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-2)(11,5)
  \begin{optexp}
    \definecolor[ps]{bl}{rgb}{tx@addDict begin Red Green Blue end}%
    \psset[optexp]{mirrortype=extended, gratingalign=c}
    
    \pnodes(1.5, 4){LaserIn}(2, 4){LaserOut}
    \pnodes (5, 4) {BSIn} (4, 3.5) {BSOut} (4, 4){BSCenter}
    \pnodes (7, 4) {MCenter} (6, 3) {Mout}
    \pnodes (5.5, 2.5) {GICenter} (6.5, 2.5) {GIOut}
    \pnodes (7.5, 2.5) {LIOut} (7, 2.5) {LICenter} (8, 2.5) {LIICenter} (8.5, 2.5) {LIIOut}
    \pnodes (10, 2.5) {GIICenter} (8.5, 3.5) {GIIOut}

    %Stretcher stage
    \mirror[compname=StretcherM1](BSIn)(MCenter)(Mout)
    \optgrating[reverse, fillstyle=solid, compname=StretcherG1](Mout)(GICenter)(GIOut)
    \lens[compname=StretcherL1](GIOut)(LIOut)
    \lens[compname=StretcherL2](LIOut)(LIIOut)
    \optgrating[compname=StretcherG2, fillstyle=solid](LIIOut)(GIICenter)(GIIOut)
    \mirror[compname=StretcherM2](GIICenter)(GIIOut)(GIICenter)

    %Fancy beams in stretcher
    \multido{\i=0+1}{40}{%
        \pstVerb{\i\space 650 400 sub 39 div mul 400 add tx@addDict begin wavelengthToRGB end}%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, beamangle=\i\space 16 sub 0.2 mul, n=1.3]{StretcherG1}{StretcherL1}{StretcherL2}{StretcherG2}%
        \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, loadbeampoints]{StretcherG2}{StretcherM2}%
    }%
    
%     %Amp stage
     \pnodes (4, 2.5) {AmpIn} (4, 0.5) {AmpOut}
    
%     %Compressor stage
     \pnodes (4, -1) {BSIICenter} (5, -1) {BSIIOut}
     \pnodes (7, -1) {MIICenter} (6, 0) {MIIOut}
     \pnodes (5.5, 0.5) {GIIICenter} (6.5, 0.5) {GIIIOut}
     \pnodes (8.5, 0.5) {GIVCenter} (8, 1) {GIVOut}
     \pnode (7.5, -0.5) {MREFCenter}
%     %Output
     \pnode(1.5, -1) {CPAOut}
    
% %   
     \beamsplitter[compname=BS1](BSIn)(BSCenter)(BSOut)
     \optbox[optboxsize=2 1, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red!40!black, compname=Amp](BSCenter)(BSIICenter)
    
     \beamsplitter[compname=BS2](AmpOut)(BSIICenter)(BSIIOut)
     \mirror[compname=CompressorM1](BSIIOut)(MIICenter)(MIIOut)
     \mirror[compname=CompressorM2](GIVCenter)(MREFCenter)(GIVCenter)
     \optgrating[reverse, fillstyle=solid, compname=CompressorG1] (MIIOut)(GIIICenter)(GIIIOut)
     \optgrating[angle = -45, fillstyle=solid, compname=CompressorG2](GIIIOut)(GIVCenter)(MREFCenter)

     %Fancy beams in compressor
     \multido{\i=0+1}{40}{%
     \pstVerb{\i\space 650 400 sub 39 div mul 400 add tx@addDict begin wavelengthToRGB end}%
         \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, beamangle=\i\space 16 sub 0.2 mul]{CompressorG1}{CompressorG2}%
         \drawbeam[linecolor=bl, loadbeampoints]{CompressorG2}{CompressorM2}
       }%
       
     % finally draw all beam between the respective components
       \drawbeam[ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsideMinLength=1](LaserIn){BS1}{StretcherM1}{StretcherG1}
       \drawbeam[ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsideMinLength=1, beaminsidefirst]{BS1}{Amp}{BS2}{CompressorM1}{CompressorG1}
       \drawbeam[ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsideMinLength=1, beaminsidefirst]{BS2}(CPAOut)
    \end{optexp}
    
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]